# Memory usage increases if block is run in a queue

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-blocks

I create a queue

```
dispatch_queue_t serialq = dispatch_queue_create("com.osletek.hill-billy", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

and put my blocks in it in a timer event, my memory usage keeps going up:

```
-(void) onTimer
{
 __weak typeof(self) this = self;
 dispatch_async(serialq, ^{
  UIImage *img = [this screenShot];
  // do something with img ...
 });
}
}
```

Without the queue, it works fine:

```
-(void) onTimer
{
 __weak typeof(self) this = self;

  UIImage *img = [this screenShot];
  // do something with img ...

}
}
```

I am using ARC.

Looks like the img object is not getting released if its in the queue.

How can I fix this mess?

Comment: Try to encapsulate the code that is in the queue with `@autoreleasepool{}`

Comment: @autoreleasepool {} did not help. What finally helped was removing UIImage related code and using CGImageRef instead. UIImage does causes memory retention problems if not used in the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

There is no defined autorelease pool when running in a queue.   There is when a timer fires.

Thus, change your code to this:

```
__weak typeof(self) this = self;
   dispatch_async(serialq, ^{
      @autorelease {
          UIImage *img = [this screenShot];
          // do something with img ...
      }
    });
}
```

`UIImage` should not cause issues when used from the non-main thread and the documentation explicitly states this.   If that still shows memory accretion, I'd suggest you use the Allocations instrument to find out what and why.